# Merge Query is taking very Long time to execute In oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization, database-performance

I am trying to execute this merge Query in my oracle DB it tables around 4 hours and 56 Minutes to Execute, I have also attached the execution Plan for the same. Can someone help me with how this performance issue can be resolved?

NOTE: We have already created an Index on SRC_CREATED_DATE, SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE, and PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY(Bitmap index)

```
MERGE
/*+ parallel(A) enable_parallel_dml*/
INTO
(
  SELECT
    AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
    SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
    AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_ASGN_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PROJECT_NATURAL_KEY,
    SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
    PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY
  FROM
    EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP
)
A USING
(
  SELECT
    /*+ PARALLEL(2) */
    AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
    SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
    AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_ASGN_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PROJECT_NATURAL_KEY,
    SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
    NULL
  FROM
    EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHEDULE_DAY_F_FRS_352
)
B ON
(
  A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY                                = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
  A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID                                        = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID AND A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY =
  B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND A.AA_PERSON_ASGN_NATURAL_KEY  =
  B.AA_PERSON_ASGN_NATURAL_KEY AND A.AA_PROJECT_NATURAL_KEY =
  B.AA_PROJECT_NATURAL_KEY
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE     = B.SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE = B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  WHERE
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE       >='01-SEP-2021'
  AND A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= '31-AUG-2022'
  AND A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY BETWEEN 2459443 AND 2459943;
  COMMIT;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @karthik. can you please gather execution plan again using "SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(FORMAT=>'+ALLSTATS'));" ? Or, what would be even better, - trace the statement and post trace output here. So far I can only see it took only 6 and half minutes for query to be done. All the rest time it was probably waiting for something... Perhaps the table was locked by another transaction for that time

Comment: The plan mentioned in the above comment will show you the actual execution plan and actual number of rows processed. 2M nested loop iterations is quite large number, and access to an index in parallel query may create a contention (it may be seen in the HTML type of the plan).

Comment: Are your `A.SRC_CREATED_DATE` and `A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE` actually `varchar2`s or are they `date`s? I doubt it's the cause of your slowness, but it's not a good idea to compare different datatypes or store dates as character data.

Comment: @eaolson No both A.SRC_CREATED_DATE and A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE are Date data types

Comment: You really need an Active (format) SQL Monitor report to get the runtime information to see where time is being spent.

Comment: Does your database is an Enterprise Edition and is it licensed to use a Diagnostic Pack? If it does, then you could generate ASH Report for the session which run merge statement. This kind of report have a summary of `wait events` which should be helpful in determining the source of a problem.